# How do I show tree of commits touching a particular path _plus_ one more commit?

Tags: git, git-log, gitk, git-rev-list

I want to see how the given commit relates to the history of changes to a file.

## Attempt 1:

```
gitk --select-commit=4ca5063196489705643b4b308ad9065d80be50e1 -- Makefile
```

The specified commit is not selected and not included at all.

## Attempt 2:

```
git log --no-walk --oneline  $(git rev-list HEAD -- Makefile; echo 4ca5063196489705643b4b308ad9065d80be50e1)

bf51adc Improve workarounds for building in various environments
9ddeb4d Improve "deb_heavy" target of Makefile
2b8104e Hacks for building on Debian Squeeze
22a9a34 Trailing newline in Makefile
4ca5063 man: Fix container example a bit
cd1a5d0 Debianization...
0149027 Start writing dived(1) man page
985cbac Improve generated Debian package
6875546 Manpage for dive
77c1706 tests: Add tests for non-priv functions
9dfcd8e Remove hacky __MUSL__, use NO_WHATEVER instead
838655e Support compilation with musl-gcc
5d10719 Options to manage capabilities bounding set
a714834 Debian package creation script
a04c85e Implementation of first version of dive
b1ce903 initial example
```

Better. The commit is included. But I want it to stand out. And I also want a tree.

## Attempt 3:

```
$ git log --graph --no-walk --oneline  $(git rev-list HEAD -- Makefile; echo 4ca5063196489705643b4b308ad9065d80be50e1)
* bf51adc Improve workarounds for building in various environments
| * 9ddeb4d Improve "deb_heavy" target of Makefile
| | * 2b8104e Hacks for building on Debian Squeeze
| | * 22a9a34 Trailing newline in Makefile
| | * 4ca5063 man: Fix container example a bit
| | * cd1a5d0 Debianization...
| | | * 0149027 Start writing dived(1) man page
| | | * 985cbac Improve generated Debian package
| | | * 6875546 Manpage for dive
| | | | * 77c1706 tests: Add tests for non-priv functions
| | | | | * 9dfcd8e Remove hacky __MUSL__, use NO_WHATEVER instead
| | | | | | * 838655e Support compilation with musl-gcc
| | | | | | | * 5d10719 Options to manage capabilities bounding set
| | | | | | | | * a714834 Debian package creation script
| | | | | | | | | * a04c85e Implementation of first version of dive
| | | | | | | | | * b1ce903 initial example
```

Not the correct tree. `--no-walk` and `--graph` does not play together well.

## Attempt 4:

```
gitk --no-walk --select-commit=4ca5063196489705643b4b308ad9065d80be50e1    $(git rev-list HEAD -- Makefile; echo 4ca5063196489705643b4b308ad9065d80be50e1)
```

The commit gets selected. But it does not filter by path now. Basically `gitk` seems to ignore `--no-walk`.

How do I do it properly?